# find prime number using while loop in java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I wanna find prime numbers. It divides `n` by all numbers between `2` and `(n–1)`, but it is wrong somewhere. For example `9`, it gives `true`.

Appreciate any help.

```
public void isPrime(int n) {

    int i = 2;
    while (i <= (n - 1)) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            System.out.println("It's not a prime number");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("It's a prime number");
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement `i++` is unreachable, so you don't want the `else{...}` to contain `break`. Instead, you simply want `else i++`.

Where you want the "is prime" statement is outside the loop, since you don't know `n` is prime until the loop finishes checking all the divisors.

And you don't want `break` inside the `if`; you want `return`, because otherwise it'll print "is prime".

P.S. You can make the while say `while(i < Math.sqrt(n))` to reduce iterations (think about it).

*EDIT*

You might want to make the return type `boolean` instead of printing messages, putting `return false` if there's a divisor and `return true` if there was no divisor.

Answer (score 1):

this method will return a boolean if your number is prime or not. In the for loop you can see that we first test 2. If our number isn't divisible by two then we don't have to test any even numbers. This is a very efficient way to test for prime numbers.

```
   boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for(int i=2;2*i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you break out of the loop on the first check: you divide by 2 and report the answer based only on that.

Restructure your loop so that the decision "It's a prime number" is delayed until you get all the way through the loop.  You may want to set a boolean variable for this.

Also, I recommend using a for loop, since you know the maximum number of times you'll iterate.  Note that you don't have to go to n-1, just to sqrt(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void isPrime(int n) {
    if(n % 2 == 0) {
       System.out.println("It is not a prime number");
       return;
    }   
    else {
       int i = 3;
       while(i <= Math.sqrt(n) ) {
           if( (n % i) == 0) {
              System.out.println("It is not a prime number");
              return;
           }
           i = i + 2; 
       }
    }
    System.out.println("It is a prime number");
    return;

}
```

You can do the while loop in this way, first you want to check if no is divisible by 2, if so it is not a prime number. If not check for odd nos till square root of n. Dont need to check for even, if no is not divisible by 2 it will not be divisible by any even number.

Answer (score 0):

```
//import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Primenos
{   public static void main(String args[])
    {   int no, flag = 0, a, b;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any no: ");
        no = sc.nextInt();
        a=1;
        while(a<=no)
        {
            flag=0;
            b=2;
            while(b<=a>>1)
            {
                if(a%b==0)
                {   flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
                b++;
            }
            if(flag==0)
            {   System.out.println("Prime number" + a);
            }
            else
            {   System.out.println("Not Prime number" + a);
            }
            a++;
        }
    }
}
```